# How to show auto selected to radio buttons when it comes from Loop?

Tags: angularjs, loops, radio-button, selected

I have a small application of attempt online exam. My questions set are comes from DB using loop. I want to edit my already attempted exam. I have a answer set of questions. But I am not able to show auto select to attempt radio buttons.

Here is my answer set

{"1":"A","2":"A","6":"A","10":"A","14":"A","21":"B","26":"C","31":"B","33":"C","34":"B","54":"C"}

Here my questions which I am showing on view page using loop

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<section ng-repeat="count in subject.test_count" ng-cloak  class="col col-3">
    <div class="inline-group" ng-if="count%2!='0'">
        <b style="width: 25px;display: inline-grid;">{{count}}</b>
        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{count}}"
               id="a{{subject.name}}{{count}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][count]"
               value="A" ng-checked="true">
            <label for="a{{subject.name}}{{count}}" >
            <p>A</p>
            </label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{count}}" 
               id="b{{subject.name}}{{count}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][count]" value="B">
        <label for="b{{subject.name}}{{count}}" >
            <p>B</p>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{count}}"
               id="c{{subject.name}}{{count}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][count]" value="C">  
        <label for="c{{subject.name}}{{count}}" >
            <p>C</p>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{count}}"
               id="d{{subject.name}}{{count}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][count]" value="D">
        <label for="d{{subject.name}}{{count}}" > 
            <p>D</p>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{count}}"
               id="e{{subject.name}}{{count}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][count]" value="E">
        <label for="e{{subject.name}}{{count}}" >
            <p>E</p>
        </label>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What happens with questions that don't have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that are off with this.  First is that you are ngRepeating through the values of the test_count and not the actual objects, to resolve that you're going to want to do something like this:

```
    <section ng-repeat="(key,value) in subject.test_count" ng-cloak  class="col col-3">
    {{key}} {{value}} 
    <span class="inline-group" ng-if="count%2!='0'">
        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{key}}"
               id="a{{subject.name}}{{key}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][key]"
               value="A">
            <label for="a{{subject.name}}{{key}}" >A</label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{key}}" 
               id="b{{subject.name}}{{key}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][key]" value="B">
        <label for="b{{subject.name}}{{key}}" >B</label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{key}}"
               id="c{{subject.name}}{{key}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][key]" value="C">  
        <label for="c{{subject.name}}{{key}}" >C</label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{key}}"
               id="d{{subject.name}}{{key}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][key]" value="D">
        <label for="d{{subject.name}}{{key}}" > D</label>

        <input type="radio" name="{{subject.name}}{{key}}"
               id="e{{subject.name}}{{key}}" class="input-hidden"
               ng-model="questiondata[subject.name][key]" value="E">
        <label for="e{{subject.name}}{{key}}" >E</label>

    </span>
</section>
```

Once you have your radio buttons and subject matching (I took some liberty with how I think you'd have the data setup) you need to seed the questiondata using the values you've provided above:

```
$scope.questiondata[0] = angular.copy($scope.subject.test_count);
```

Now we can see that $scope.questiondata[0][1] = $scope.subject.test_count[1] = 'A' which means that A will be selected.

Here is a sample of the full controller: https://plnkr.co/edit/fyJwfLc6Qb7b7p4ZLgqI